# What is the spawn frequency of the tank minions in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

Minion waves contain little fighters and mages. They also sometimes (?) contain little tank units. I've noticed the tank units aren't always there, what are the rules that dictate when or how often they appear?

Answer (score 13):

There are 4 types of minions that spawn.

- **Melee Minion**: Three of these minions are spawned every round.
- **Caster Minion**: Three of these minions are spawned every round.
- ***Siege Minion***: One of these minions spawn every third round. (Note: At 20 and 35 minutes the frequency is upped to every second round and lastly every round)
- **Super Minion**: One of this minion spawns in each wave if the enemy inhibitor is destroyed on that lane. If all three inhibitors are destroyed, two super minions will spawn in each wave and every lane.

Comment: @siberian Please accept answer formally (by clicking on the V-like checkmark symbol below up/down votes for the answer).